# visual studio 2022 community and blat

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022, blat

I have used the **Blat** email line below in **Studio 2017 and 2019** but it does not appear to work in **Visual Studio 2022**. Does anyone know what the issue is or suggest an alternative please?

`Shell("C:\Windows\System32\blat.exe -body "" "" -attach ""spreadsheet"" -log C:\service\MailSend.log -debug -base64 -to ""name@company.co.uk"" -subject ""report - " & Date.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("ddMMyyyy")Blat email & """ -server [ipaddress] -f ""MV_NoReply@company.co.uk""")`

many thanks

Robert Bee

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Blat is a command line SMTP client. Which is fine in batch (CMD) files and such.I've used it with great results there. But since you're using VB.NET, why not use the .NET framework's [SmtpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0) instead?

Comment: If not the built in SmtpClient then maybe MailKit